# OpenERP v7 customizing search filters

Tags: search, odoo

I would like to have a custom set of textboxes and drop downs on the product search screen, where people can select or input filter values and hit search. The grid below would show the products that fit the required criteria.

How can this be achieved in openerp?

Here is what I have tried:

```
    <record id="product_search_form_view_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product_search_form_view_custom</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_search_form_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <field name="name" position="after">
                    <field name="product_type"/>
                </field>                   
        </field>
    </record>
```

But it doesn't really show up anywhere on product search screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is very much limited things that you can do with search screen. You can add `filters`, or fields that can be searched based on the value. Rest is there in "Advance Search".